# How do I configure Android settings in a Vue/Capacitor app?

Tags: android, vue.js, capacitor

I'm building an application for web/Android with Vue+Capacitor. What's the correct way to manipulate the Android part?
For example, I'd like the screen to not turn off through idle. Apparently, the way to do this is to put
`getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);` 
in the MainActivity. But since the Android part gets built again all the time it doesn't really make sense to edit it directly (or maybe I'm mistaken here somehow?)

So how do I achieve something like this?

Edit for clarification:

This is the MainActivity:

```
import com.getcapacitor.BridgeActivity;
public class MainActivity extends BridgeActivity {}
```

As you can see it does absolutely nothing besides extending BridgeActivity

This is the (generated!) onCreate of BridgeActivity:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        bridgeBuilder.setInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        getApplication().setTheme(getResources().getIdentifier("AppTheme_NoActionBar", "style", getPackageName()));
        setTheme(getResources().getIdentifier("AppTheme_NoActionBar", "style", getPackageName()));
        setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_NoActionBar);
        setContentView(R.layout.bridge_layout_main);
        /* The initally mentioned line here works but gets overwritten*/
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use this community plugin: https://github.com/capacitor-community/keep-awake.
This way you don't have to change the native code.

```
import { KeepAwake } from '@capacitor-community/keep-awake';

const keepAwake = async () => {
  await KeepAwake.keepAwake();
};

const allowSleep = async () => {
  await KeepAwake.allowSleep();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you run `npx cap add android`, the native project gets created and it’s never modified by capacitor, so you can make any changes you want in the `MainActivity.java` file or any other files (except the ones that start with “automatically generated, do not edit” or similar messaging).

Comment: thanks, but could you expand a bit on this? The MainActivity is empty, only extends BridgeActivity which of course is built by vue. If I add the mentioned code in BridgeActivity, of course it works but will be overwritten the next time I build the app.
How do I actually add code in the MainActivity so that it runs in the onCreate ?

Comment: Capacitor doesn’t overwrite the MainActivity.java code, never, if it’s getting overwritten it’s not capacitor who is doing it. Also not sure what do you mean by “which of course is built by vue”

Comment: Edited the original post with the two Activities. It's probably just because I'm an Android noob but I guess the question is: You're right, the MainActivity isn't being overwritten. But I'm not sure how to add code that actually gets executed in there since it doesn't have any onCreate or anything itself...

Comment: You can add the onCreate yourself